# Fix last drop down element while scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using JQuery token-Input plugin. And I want to fix last element of my drop-down when i scroll it. 
I have tried the approach from [this](https://jsfiddle.net/vyLk778k/1/) fiddle. But no luck.

This is my code here and attached is the image that is working fine, but it displays the links at the end of scroll.
I want to fix these links and display them whenever user types something.

[image]

```css
div.token-input-dropdown-paracas {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 2px;
  background-color: #fff;
  overflow: auto;
  max-height: 400px;
  min-width: 150px;
  border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  cursor: default;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-family: "Open Sans", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  z-index: 1;
  p {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #777;
  }
  ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 2px;
    height: auto !important;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    min-height: 1px;
    @include border-radius(2px);
    li {
      overflow: hidden;
      height: auto !important;
      height: 15px;
      margin: 3px;
      padding: 2px 5px 3px 5px;
      background-color: #cce5f9;
      color: #388be9;
      cursor: default;
      border: none;
      border-radius: 2px;
      -moz-border-radius: 2px;
      -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
      white-space: nowrap;
      &.token-input-project-token-paracas {
        background: #fbc07f;
      }
      &.token-input-department-token-paracas {
        background: #E6F8DD;
      }
      &.token-input-selected-dropdown-item-paracas {
        background-color: #3b5998;
        color: #fff;
      }
      em {
        font-weight: bold;
        font-style: normal;
      }
    }
    span.token-input-dropdown-heading-paracas {
      margin: 0 0 5px 5px;
      color: #555555;
      font-weight: 600;
      font-size: 13px;
    }
  }
  hr {
    margin: 5px 5px;
    border-top: 1px solid #C0C0C0;
  }
  a.token-input-dropdown-link-paracas {
    display: block;
    margin: 5px;
    font-size: 13px;
  }
}
```

```html
    <div class="token-input-dropdown-paracas" style="">
      <ul style="">
        <li class="token-input-dropdown-item2-paracas token-input-selected-dropdown-item-paracas">last_email@yahoo.com &lt;last_email@yahoo.com&gt;</li>
         <li class="token-input-dropdown-item-paracas">sdfs sdfsd &lt;sdfsdfsdfsd@gmail.com&gt;</li>
         <li class="token-input-dropdown-item-paracas">sdfs sdfsd &lt;Test_email@yahoo.cm&gt;</li>
         <li class="token-input-dropdown-item-paracas">sdfs sdfsd &lt;skdfsdfsdfsd@gmail.com&gt;</li>

        <hr>
          <a class="token-input-dropdown-link-paracas show-overlay create-new-contact" href="/settings/contacts/new?new_dialog=true&amp;field_id=meeting_required_participant_ids">Create New</a></ul>
    </div
```

Comment: Is this acceptable? https://jsfiddle.net/pf03etdn/

Comment: I have tried this but did not work in my case.

Comment: Step 1: Fix your faulty HTML. You can not drop whatever you like into an unordered list, you need to use list items as children.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the below one. Just added one empty list item before the last one (view all items) and some styling changes. Its kind of workaround but it may be a fix for your issue.

```js
$('.scrollable-bootstrap-menu').scroll(function(){
$('.scrollable-bootstrap-menu li:last-child').css('bottom',-$(this).scrollTop());

}
);
```

```css
li{
  list-style:none;
}
.scrollable-bootstrap-menu {
height: auto;
  max-height: 100px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
position:relative;
}
.scrollable-bootstrap-menu li:last-child {
position:absolute;
bottom:0;
background:#fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="dropdown-menu scrollable-bootstrap-menu">
      <li><a href='#'>First</a></li>
      <li><a href='#'>item2</a></li>
      <li><a href='#'>item3</a></li>
      <li><a href='#'>item4</a></li>      
      <li><a href='#'>item1</a></li>
      <li><a href='#'>item2</a></li>
      <li><a href='#'>item3</a></li>
      <li><a href='#'>item4</a></li>      <li><a href='#'>item1</a></li>
      <li><a href='#'>item2</a></li>
      <li><a href='#'>item3</a></li>
      <li><a href='#'>item4</a></li>      <li><a href='#'>item1</a></li>
      <li><a href='#'>item2</a></li>
      <li><a href='#'>item3</a></li>
      <li><a href='#'>item4</a></li>      <li><a href='#'>item1</a></li>
      <li><a href='#'>item2</a></li>
      <li><a href='#'>item3</a></li>
      <li><a href='#'>item4</a></li>      <li><a href='#'>item1</a></li>
      <li><a href='#'>item2</a></li>
      <li><a href='#'>item3</a></li>
      <li><a href='#'>item4</a></li>      <li><a href='#'>item1</a></li>
      <li><a href='#'>item2</a></li>
      <li><a href='#'>item3</a></li>
      <li><a href='#'>item4</a></li>      <li><a href='#'>item1</a></li>
      <li><a href='#'>item2</a></li>
      <li><a href='#'>item3</a></li>
      <li><a href='#'>last</a></li>
      <li>&nbsp;</li>
  <li><a href='#'>View all items</a></li>
</ul>
```